# Web Audio API is not working properly, in google chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, web-audio-api

I've created a simple music player, which creates a `bufferArray` for a particular audio URL to play the music.

> It is working fine in many of my cellphone's browser, so I guess there is no cross origin issue for audio URL.

### however chrome is not playing audio.

Also I've created a `Uint8Array` for plotting frequency data inside `canvas`, while many browsers are plotting frequency graph in `canvas` successfully, chrome is not doing so!

### Take a look at what I've tried so far!

````html
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <h1>Music Player</h1>
    <hr>
    <div id="div"></div>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <p>Frequency plot</p>
    </center>
    <script>
    url = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/5jyylqps64nyoez/Legends%20never%20die.mp3?dl=0";
    const div = document.querySelector("#div");
    const cvs = document.querySelector("canvas");
    cvs.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
    cvs.height = 200;
    const c = cvs.getContext("2d");
    function loadMusic(url){
 div.innerHTML = "Loading music, please wait...";
        const context = new AudioContext();
        const source = context.createBufferSource();
        const analyser = context.createAnalyser();
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET",url,true);
        request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        request.onload = ()=>{
            div.innerHTML = "Music loaded, please wait, music will be played soon...";
context.decodeAudioData(request.response,suffer=>{
    source.buffer = suffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
    source.start();
    div.innerHTML = "Music is playing... Enjoy!";
    setInterval(()=>{
c.clearRect(0,0,cvs.width,cvs.height);
let array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
let m = 0;
for(m = 0; m < array.length; m++){
    let x = (parseInt(window.innerWidth -20)*m)/array.length;
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(x,150-((100*array[m])/255));
    c.lineTo((parseInt(window.innerWidth -20)*(m+1))/array.length,150-((100*array[m+1])/255));
    c.lineWidth = 1;
    c.strokeStyle = "black";
    c.stroke();

}
},1);
});
        }
        request.send();
    }
   
        loadMusic(url);
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>

```
````

Comment: Hi, I've tried your snippet on Windows 10 on Edge, Chrome and Firefox and they all work. In Safari and Chrome on IOS however it doesn't get past the loading stage and there seems to be a script error (which I haven't tracked down).

Comment: Chrome on IOS gives the same result (ie not playing) as Safari on IOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a couple of observations than a complete solution.

The code given worked for me on Edge, Chrome and Firefox on Windows 10.

On IOS 14 Safari and IOS 14 Chrome it seemed to stop after putting out the loading message.

This [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext#:%7E:text=The%20AudioContext%20interface%20represents%20an%20audio-processing%20graph%20built,the%20execution%20of%20the%20audio%20processing%2C%20or%20decoding.) reference used a 'cross browser' method to create audiocontext so I added this line:

```
 var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
```

before this line:

```
 const context = new AudioContext();
```

[edit: have just confirmed at [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=audio-api) that -webkit prefix needed by Safari]

That seemed to do the trick in as much as the rest of the code was executed. However, there was no sound and it appeared the audio was not playing. The plot also showed just a single horizontal line.

Is this a manifestation of IOS's requirement that there must be some user interaction before audio will actually be played?

I'm pretty sure the audio was loaded as there was a noticeable pause at that point. I suspect that there will have to be a button which when clicked actually starts the playing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, finally I'm able to know the problem, it is actually a `button` that I need to add, it seems for large enough buffer, autoplay is restricted by some of the browsers, I've added the button, and now it is working fine, also frequency plot is working too, as audio is playing so canvas is able to fetch data.

Comment: Glad it worked. Does IOS require a button anyway? (It won't autoplay sound I believe).

Comment: I have not tested it for iPhone yet, but in my device some of the browsers were able to autoplay sound while some of the other browsers were not able to do so. I guess it may have something to do with either browser's policy or size of the `arraybuffer` ...